# App with MVC Virtual application shared AuthCookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a 3.5 ASP.Net WebForm parent application.  The parent uses forms authentication.
 I have a MVC child virtual application, I would like to make it so the user logs in to the parent application, user then navigates to the virtual application by pressing a link on the parent.
 However every time I do this it goes to the login screen for the virtual application.

Is there a web setting I should double check in Parent?   Or Child?

Is there an IIS setting that I should check?

Should I be using a virtual directory instead of virtual application?  I want the child to be able to access the Session[] from the parent.  I would like the child app to use the same authCookie as the parent app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single signon scenario's make sure in the web config:

[Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
algorithms must also be the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

You may need to set [EnableCrossAppRedirects="true"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.aspx), depending on how you have configured your app.